# MAT 2001 Oxford Admissions Exam Solution Verification

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification

I have been doing some old MAT past papers, to which there is no mark scheme available, and I was wondering if anybody can check my work on the following question:

[image]
[image]

**My Answers:**

**(a)**
The shortest path is of length 2 and there are two such paths.

**(b and c)**
The possible path lengths are $2,4$ and $6$. There are $3$ paths of length $6$.

**(d)**
**No**. Consider the following labeling:

[image]

We must either have $\vec{AC}$ and $\vec{GC}$ or $\vec{GC}$ twice. If we have $\vec{GC}$ twice then we would have to cross $A$ or $B$ twice which would be a contradiction. Thus we must have $\vec{AC}$ and $\vec{GC}$. Similarly, we must have $\vec{DB}$ and $\vec{AD}$. However, this is a contradiction as $A$ can't have two paths from it (since this would imply that $A$ is crossed twice. Thus, the answer is **No**.

Comment: There are more than 3 paths of length 6. I counted 5

Comment: The answer of (c) is wrong unless I am making a mistake...I have counted 8 paths.